# How do I search for a value in a different sheet, possibly within a string of text

Tags: match, google-sheets-formula, counting, countif, partial-matches

I have values I need to search for within another sheet (4 columns), the fourth column's cells containing strings of text. I need a formula that is able to search for and count how many times the value shows up in the other sheet, even within a string of text. Preferably I'd like it find the exact match of the text. Sometimes a cell will be 'abcd' and it will count 'abcd1.'

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet2!A:D, A30)
```

So far this only gets me the amount of times the value shows up when on its own in a cell, but not within the string of text. I believe there will also be some concatenating involved for some of the values. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet2!A:D, "*"&A30&"*")
```

or:

```
=INDEX(SUM(IFERROR(REGEXMATCH(Sheet2!A:D&"", ".*"&A30&".*")*1, 0)))
```

Comment: The top one worked, thank you!! Can you explain what's going on at the end? before i was using asterisks, but not within quotations.

Comment: @andie_6655321 sure, we just appended asterisk wildcard `*` in front and at the end so countif will try to find A30 even in those cells which contains A30 and something more in either direction